# Open nyromodal from jquery-ui dialog is behind the dialog

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog, nyromodal

I'm trying to show an image with nyromodal. I'm trying to do from a jquery-ui dialog, but the nyromodal is showing behind the dialog.
How can I change so the image goes to the front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add the properties `z-index` in nyroModal.css.
I added the `z-index` in `.nyroModalBg, .nyroModalCloseButton, .nyroModalTitle, .nyroModalCont, .nyroModalCont iframe, .nyroModalLoad` to solve  similar problems.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will try and comeback later